# How to view generated managed object category/extension in XCode Editor

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

In Core data when I create a data model, I choose to generate the category extension, I understand that this is created in derived data

[image]
I want to be able to view this in the XCode code editor but I don't know how I can open it just to **view** it.

I am using XCode 9 beta 3

The ways I can manage to do this is by typing some thing such as

```
let m  = MenuItem()
let n = m.name
```

In the code editor and then command clicking on **name** and then it jumps to the file, or finding the generated extension in Finder and opening from there.

```
//
//  MenuItem+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Ryan.Heitner on 01/08/2017.
//
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension MenuItem {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MenuItem> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MenuItem>(entityName: "MenuItem")
    }

    @NSManaged public var available: Bool
    @NSManaged public var desc: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var price: Double

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The category extension seems buggy to me. Just select "Manual/None", then select an entity or all entities and click on Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass, choose your entities and the extensions should be shown under your project root in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you're doing is the only option Xcode provides. It's not good, but you haven't missed anything. I suggest filing a bug with Apple about this. In the meantime, either deal with this as it is, or switch to some other means of generating your properties-- manually maybe, or using [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator).